# Delete button for each row with restriction

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in mysql database, the first one is 'kavomati' where are coffee machines and second table is 'lokacije' where are locations of those coffee machines. I created one page where I see all locations and there I have modal button for add new location, modal buttons for edit each location and at the end of each address I added delete modal button for each row. What I want to do is to delete every location which has no coffee machine but first I must make a query in php and check is certain location have any coffee machine. I'm newbie in php and this is my homework problem so I would appreciate any help.

This is my code to display locations of my database table and modal buttons:

```
    <?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    header('Location: ../../index.php');
}
try{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT id,ulica,kc_broj,mjesto FROM lokacije ORDER BY id ASC');
    $stmt->execute();
    $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    if(DEBUG === true){
        header('Location:error/db_error.php?err_msg='.$e->getMessage());
    }
    else{
        header('Location:error/db_error.php?err_msg');
    }
  }
?>
<div class="panel-heading clearfix">
<h3 style="float:left; margin:0;">Lokacije</h3>
<a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_locModal" role="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="float:right;">Dodaj lokaciju</a>
</div>
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Ulica</th>
        <th>Kućni broj</th>
        <th>Mjesto</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        foreach($data as $value){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo $value['id'].'.'?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $value['ulica']?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $value['kc_broj']?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $value['mjesto']?>
        </td>
        <td align="right">

            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit_loc<?php echo $value['id']?>" role="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm edit">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Uredi
            </a>

            <div class="modal fade edit-u" id="edit_loc<?php echo $value['id']?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content" style="text-align:left;">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Uredi lokaciju broj <?php echo $value['id']?></h4>
                        </div>
                        <form action="" method="POST">
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <input type="hidden" name="id_lokacije" id="id_lokacije" value="<?php echo $value['id']?>">
                                <div class="form-group ulica">
                                    <label for="ulica">Ulica</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ulica" id="ulica-u" placeholder="Ostavite prazno polje ako ne želite mjenjati naziv kavomata" value="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group kc_broj">
                                    <label for="kc_broj">Kućni broj</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="kc_broj" id="kc_broj-u" placeholder="Ostavite prazno polje ako ne želite mjenjati naziv kavomata" value="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group mjesto">
                                    <label for="mjesto">Mjesto</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mjesto" id="mjesto-u" placeholder="Ostavite prazno polje ako ne želite mjenjati naziv kavomata" value="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Zatvori</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="edit_loc">Spremi</button>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete_loc<?php echo $value['id']?>" role="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Izbriši
            </a>

                <div class="modal fade" id="delete_loc<?php echo $value['id']?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content" style="text-align:center;">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                                <h2 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" style="color:#a80b27;text-transform:uppercase;font-size:1.6rem;">upozorenje   !</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <h5>Da li si siguran da želiš obrisati lokaciju broj <b><?php echo $value['id']?></b>?</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <a href="include/locations/delete.php?id=<?php echo $value['id']?>" role="button" class="btn btn-danger">
                                    Da, siguran sam!
                                </a>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Ne</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</table>


<div class="modal fade" id="add_locModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Dodaj novu lokaciju</h4>
        </div>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group ulica">
                    <label for="ulica">Ulica</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ulica" id="ulica" placeholder="Ulica">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group kc_broj">
                    <label for="kc_broj">Kućni broj</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="kc_broj" id="kc_broj" placeholder="Kućni broj">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mjesto">
                    <label for="mjesto">Mjesto</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mjesto" id="mjesto" placeholder="Mjesto">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Zatvori</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add_loc">Dodaj</button>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my delete.php script:

```
require '../../config/init.php';
require '../services/xss.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    try{
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('DELETE FROM lokacije WHERE id=:id NOT IN(SELECT k.id FROM kavomati k WHERE k.id=lokacije.id)');
        $stmt->bindParam(':id',$id);
        $stmt->execute();
        header('Location:../../coffee-locations.php');
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        if(DEBUG === true){
            header('Location:../../error/db_error.php?err_msg='.$e->getMessage());
        }
        else{
            header('Location:../../error/db_error.php?err_msg');
        }
    }
}
else{
    header('Location:../../index.php');
}
?>
```

I tried something like this but it doesn't work.

Comment: See CASCADE ON DELETE

Comment: We are not supposed to help with homework

Comment: You MUST be getting an error message from the delete query, either the prepare or execute. WHAT IS IT

Comment: Thanks for reply. Strawberry, relations in database must stay as it is. It is set RESTRICT ON DELETE.